# data rows of datagridview wont upload as rows only upload one row and button wont disable

Tags: c#

this is my method to insert all data from datagridview to database and i works perfectly without the resetall method i used to reset all textboxes and datagridview after uploading the data to sql....but when i use the method the rows wont record..for example if there is 5 rows in datagridview only one gets recorded...

if i dont use the reset method my make payment button wont go way as i can keep uploading the same data multiple times from the datagridview to database and i dont want that...ill attach some images below

I want to make the make payment button disable after uploading each time to the database

THIS IS MY CODE

```
public void uploadrecords() //insert bulk data from datagridview to database
    {
        string mainconn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(mainconn);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridViewCart.Rows)
        {
            string sqlquery = "insert into tblCart values(@billid, @selldate, @sellername, @cdesc, @price, @qty, @total)";
            SqlCommand sqlcomm = new SqlCommand(sqlquery, sqlconn);
            if (dr.IsNewRow) continue; //to not insert null values of the datagridview rows
            {
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billid", dr.Cells["billid"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selldate", dr.Cells["selldate"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sellername", dr.Cells["sellername"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cdesc", dr.Cells["cdesc"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", dr.Cells["price"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", dr.Cells["qty"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
                sqlcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total", dr.Cells["total"].Value ?? DBNull.Value);
            }
            sqlconn.Open();
            sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlconn.Close();
            lblconfirm.Text = "Payment Successful Dont forget to thank your customer!";
            resetallmethod();

        }
```

HERE IS A IMAGE OF DATABASE WHEN I UPLOAD 5 ROWS with RESETALL METHOD
[image]

IMAGE OF INTERFACE
[image]

Comment: Where is code for resetallmethod?

Comment: public void resetallmethod()
        {
            lblconfirm.Text = "";
            lblBal.Text = "";
            txtBal.Text = "";
            lblTotal.Text = "";
            txtGrandTotal.Text = "";
            txtDisc.Text = "";
            txtPay.Text = "";
            txtTotal.Text = "";
            txtQty.Text = "";
            lblTransno.Text = "000000000000000";
            txtNet.Text = "";
            dataGridViewCart.Rows.Clear();
        }  THIS IS THE CODE

Comment: @jdweng i posted the code

Comment: remove `dataGridViewCart.Rows.Clear();` and then test

Comment: Using DataTables would make your life a lot easier

Comment: tried that same even if i remove the line thank you for the suggestion